# SQL Query to Set/Match the Null Values for a Column Based on If a Sub Field is Included/Contained in a Main Fields Identifier

Tags: sql, mysql

I have something like the View below that is incredibly large.

Where the "Category" column is Null, I need to return the Category based on the rows where category is NOT null. The logic should be that IF the Category is NULL and the Sub_Identifier is CONTAINED in the main identifier string, THEN that matching Category should be set for that line item in the row.

[Chart Image from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASCZO.png)

Based on the example chart, I'm expecting something like this to return and be set in my view.

[Excel Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzYuB.png)

The part where I am stuck is related to returning/setting the matches in the Category column for the Sub_Identifiers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correct. Here is my idea what you want to do, maybe it helps? https://dbfiddle.uk/tVpDiy7o

Comment: @JonasMetzler this worked wonderfully, thank you! But I actually realized I'm working in a view and not a table. Can you please let me know how I would achieve this with my view?

Comment: What do you mean? Updating a view is mostly not possible or does not make sense. A view is usually a result of a query of one or more tables. So the data shown in the view will not directly be modified. It will change when the data of the affected tables change.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and easier to understand approach to solve this -

```sql
UPDATE YourTable AS t1
SET Category = t2.Category
FROM YourTable AS t2
WHERE t1.Category IS NULL
  AND t2.Category IS NOT NULL
  AND POSITION(t2.Sub_Identifier IN t1.Main_Identifier) > 0;
```

Firstly, we update the "Category" column in "YourTable" table (aliased as t1) and then; using a self-join with another instance of the "YourTable" table (aliased as t2), we're checking for rows where the "Category" in the target row (t1) is null and the "Category" in the source row (t2) is not null. We're also using the `POSITION` function to check if the "Sub_Identifier" in the source row (t2) is contained within the "Main_Identifier" of the target row (t1). If the conditions are met, we're updating the "Category" in the target row with the "Category" from the source row.

Comment: Thank you, Abdul. I really appreciate your help on this one. I do get an error with this that stated mismatched input 'FROM' expecting EOF. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think Abdul’s answer is nearly there. You need another condition that excludes the T1 rows with a non-null Main Category from the update. Also check the MySQL update syntax for updates using multiple tables. Look out too for situations where the T2 reference table might return multiple rows unexpectedly - this will lead to failures.

Comment: @v0rl0n thank you very much for letting me know. It is actually a View, rather than a table, do you have any advice on this?

Comment: The fact it is a view should not matter.  Work on getting the update working in principle (using the T1/T2 approach suggested by Abdul) in MySQL syntax.  Then maybe consider my points, if appropriate.